# How to transform string into monetary value?

Tags: python

The input data is from an external API. The integer should be transformed to human readable currency with the last two digits as penny values.

ex: I receive this: '0000000702870'. I want the format `7.028,70`.

Always the last two values will be penny values.

I try this

```py
float(value)
```

but i get this 702870.0

And this

```py
def convert_received_value_parser(value, sep='.'):
    value = str(value)
    return value if len(value) <= 4 else convert_received_value_parser(value[:-5], sep) + sep + value[-5:]
```

However, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
value = '0000000702870'
v = float(value)/100
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'pt_BR')
out = locale.format('%.2f',v,grouping=True)


print(out)
```

output:

```
'7.028,70'
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this

Comment: sorry for the delay but my get was 7028,70

Comment: maybe try locale.format_string instead of locale.format because it is being deprecated?but strange, either way I get my output using your input string

Comment: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'pt_BR') Works

Comment: strange the other wouldnt work for you? but either way glad you got it to work

Comment: Thanks so much Bro